# EntityFramework Core chamada de tabelas distintas

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Gostaria de filtrar uma lista, pelo Id de um Colaborador, meu problema é que na hora de retornar a lista ele retorna tudo do banco.

Preciso filtrar por exemplo todos Projetos que o Colaborador com Id=10 está envolvido, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estou usando Asp.net Core e EF.

**Classe ClienteProjetoColaborador**

```
public class ClienteProjetoColaborador
{
    public int IdClienteProjetoColaborador { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Projeto")]
    public int? IdProjeto { get; set; }

    [Display (Name ="Cliente")]
    public int? IdCliente { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Colaborador")]
    public int? IdColaborador { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Atividade")]
    public int? IdAtividade { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public int? IdStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
    public int? IdTipoStatusAtividade { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Inicial")]
    public DateTime? DataInicial { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Final")]
    public DateTime? DataFinal { get; set; }

    public decimal? EsforcoEstimado { get; set; }
    public decimal? EsforcoReal { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioLog { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataLog { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoLog { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Atividade")]
    public virtual Atividade IdAtividadeNavigation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
    public virtual Cliente IdClienteNavigation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Colaborador")]
    public virtual Colaboradores IdColaboradorNavigation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Projeto")]
    public virtual Projeto IdProjetoNavigation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public virtual StatusProjeto IdStatusNavigation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public virtual TipoStatusAtividade IdTipoStatusAtividadeNavigation { get; set; }

    public Colaboradores Colaboradores { get; set; }
    List<ClienteProjetoColaborador> ClienteProjetoColaboradores { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Colaboradores**

```
 public class Colaboradores
{
    public Colaboradores()
    {
        CalculoProjeto = new HashSet<CalculoProjeto>();
        ClienteProjetoColaborador = new HashSet<ClienteProjetoColaborador>();
        ProjetoIdGerenteContaNavigation = new HashSet<Projeto>();
        ProjetoIdResponsavelCptNavigation = new HashSet<Projeto>();
    }

    public int IdColaborador { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nome Colaborador")]
    public string NomeColaborador { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
    public int IdDepartamento { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cargo")]
    public int IdCargo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Custo Total Colaborador")]
    public int? IdCustoTotalColaborador { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioLog { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataLog { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoLog { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cargo")]
    public virtual Cargo IdCargoNavigation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Custo Colaborador")]
    public virtual CustoTotalColaborador IdCustoTotalColaboradorNavigation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
    public virtual Departamento IdDepartamentoNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CalculoProjeto> CalculoProjeto { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteProjetoColaborador> ClienteProjetoColaborador { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Projeto> ProjetoIdGerenteContaNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Projeto> ProjetoIdResponsavelCptNavigation { get; set; }

    List<Colaboradores>listaColab { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel que retornarei**

```
    public class ViewModel
{
    [Key]
   public int ColaboradorViewModelId { get; set; } 

    public string NomeColaborador { get; set;  } //TABELA COLABORADORES

    public int? IdProjeto { get; set; } // TABELA DO PROJETO

    public int? IdCliente { get; set; } // TABELA DO CLIENTE



}
```

**Método Index que quero fazer o filtro.**

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var Id = 10;

        List<ViewModel> ListaExemplo = new List<ViewModel>();

        //CONSULTA DE DADOS NO BD

        var listaBD = (from Colaboradores in _context.Colaboradores
                       join ClienteProjetoColaborador in _context.ClienteProjetoColaborador on Colaboradores.IdColaborador equals ClienteProjetoColaborador.IdColaborador

                       select new { Colaboradores.IdColaborador, Colaboradores.NomeColaborador, ClienteProjetoColaborador.IdCliente, ClienteProjetoColaborador.IdProjeto }).ToList();




        //PERCORRE A LISTA DE CLIENTES E PREENCHE A VIEW MODEL

        foreach (var item in listaBD)
        {
            ViewModel VMColab = new ViewModel();
            VMColab.ColaboradorViewModelId = item.IdColaborador;
            VMColab.NomeColaborador = item.NomeColaborador;
            VMColab.IdCliente = item.IdCliente;
            VMColab.IdProjeto = item.IdProjeto;
            ListaExemplo.Add(VMColab);
        }



        return View(ListaExemplo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para filtrar no Entity Framework basta usar o [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) (Consulta integrada à Linguagem) na chamada do context.

Por exemplo, se quero filtrar todos os Colaboradores que tem o Id com valor 10 é só fazer a chamada dessa maneira

```
 var listaBD = _context.Colaboradores.Where(x => x.IdColaborador == 10);
```

Porém como no seu caso, o campo está sinalizado como Primary Key (sinalizando que não pode se repetir na tabela), então não é necessário selecionar todos que tem esse Id(até porque só retornaria um elemento), logo você pode trocar o `Where` por `First`, resultando nessa chamada:

```
var listaBD = (from Colaboradores in _context.Colaboradores.First(x => x.IdColaborador == 10)
    join ClienteProjetoColaborador in _context.ClienteProjetoColaborador on Colaboradores.IdColaborador equals ClienteProjetoColaborador.IdColaborador

    select new { Colaboradores.IdColaborador, Colaboradores.NomeColaborador, ClienteProjetoColaborador.IdCliente, ClienteProjetoColaborador.IdProjeto }).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado! esclareceu minhas dúvidas

Comment: Sem problemas meu bom, pode contar com o pessoal do SOpt pra tudo! ;)